# Creating a new directory in C

Tags: c, linux, directory

I want to write a program that checks for the existence of a directory; if that directory does not exist then it creates the directory and a log file inside of it, but if the directory already exists, then it just creates a new log file in that folder.

How would I do this in C with Linux?

Comment: mkdir function creates a new directory, http://blog.tremend.ro/2008/10/06/create-directories-in-c-using-mkdir-with-proper-permissions/

Comment: maybe that's because you can find the solution in google or even in here by making a simple search http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=C+make+directory. By the way I'm not the guy who has down voted.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @TobySpeight That is not good advice for this question at all. This question is far too broad, and there is no "specific problem" that is not covered by the question as it is. The problem is to find a way to create a directory in C. Polluting the question with the OP's specific code would likely greatly reduce the applicability to the countless other users that would reach this page.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Look at [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) for checking if the directory exists,

And [`mkdir`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir), to create a directory.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct stat st = {0};

if (stat("/some/directory", &st) == -1) {
    mkdir("/some/directory", 0700);
}
```

You can see the manual of these functions with the `man 2 stat` and `man 2 mkdir` commands.

Comment: I believe `mkdir` under Linux needs a second parameter, `mode`, in addition to `path`.

Comment: Paul R: it's not mandatory, it just gets effective id as the owner

Comment: @Uku Loskit: won't you get a compile error if you pass only one parameter ?

Comment: @Uku: did you compile with gcc -Wall ?

Comment: @Uku: maybe you're compiling C++ (and in that language maybe there is a version of `mkdir()` with only 1 parameter ...) ...

Comment: i'm compiling with gcc. It gives me warnings with -Wall, but still compiles.

Comment: @Uku: passing an incorrect number of parameters to a function is Undefined Behaviour, so while it may appear to work for you in one instance you should not rely on it.

Comment: I found it odd that execute bit was set.  Apparently permissions are interpreted differently for folders.  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/why-do-directories-need-the-executable-x-permission-to-be-opened

Comment: What is the purpose of checking that the directory doesn't exist before creating it? Even if stat says it doesn't exist yet, another process could have created it in the meantime.

Comment: @Brandin I guess I blindly answered to OP's question :) You are right about the race condition.

Comment: This will be flagged by most good static analyzers as a TOCTOU risk

Comment: How can I add another option like `$mkdir -p ./parent_dir/my_dir/`?

Comment: error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory

Answer (score 35):

You can use mkdir:

[$ man 2 mkdir](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir)

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int result = mkdir("/home/me/test.txt", 0777);
```

Comment: Will this remove and replace existing directories?

Comment: @jjxtra:: no, it should fail if the directory already exists, in much the same way as if you had attempted the same operation from the command line.

Comment: That's what I would have guessed. Any performance problem by skipping the stat check and just mkdir every time?

Comment: @jjxtra: unless you're creating thousands of directories I can't imagine there would be any measurable performance difference.

Comment: Trying `mkdir()` directly instead of doing a `stat()` first is faster, as it saves one system call, if the directory is created. If the directory does already exit, then the successful `stat()` will still be slower than the unsuccessful `mkdir()`, as `stat()` has to do more work to complete.

Comment: Looking at the manual page of `mkdir`, an additional check I would add is this `if(mkdir(...) < 0 && errno != EEXIST) { /* mkdir failed due to some other reason than file/directory already existing */}`. In that case, I think it would be better to fail the program if the above if statements true.

Answer (score 12):

> I want to write a program that (...) creates the directory and a (...) file inside of it

because this is a very common question, here is the code to create multiple levels of directories and than call fopen. I'm using a gnu extension to print the error message with printf.

```
void rek_mkdir(char *path) {
    char *sep = strrchr(path, '/');
    if(sep != NULL) {
        *sep = 0;
        rek_mkdir(path);
        *sep = '/';
    }
    if(mkdir(path, 0777) && errno != EEXIST)
        fprintf(stderr, "error while trying to create '%s'\n%m\n", path); 
}

FILE *fopen_mkdir(char *path, char *mode) {
    char *sep = strrchr(path, '/');
    if(sep) { 
        char *path0 = strdup(path);
        path0[ sep - path ] = 0;
        rek_mkdir(path0);
        free(path0);
    }
    return fopen(path,mode);
}
```

Comment: just my 5 cents - mode 0777 for dir may be not desired - maybe 0755 is better, or even pass by parameter?

Comment: @ivan.ukr 0777 is correct, the mode will by modified by the users umask.  Eg. for umask 022 it results in 755 or for umask 007 in 770.

Comment: Don't forget that `mkdir` will give `EEXIST` if some non-directory file has the specified pathname, so we'll need a test for that.

Answer (score 9):

To create a new directory in C, you can use the `mkdir` function defined in `<sys/stat.h>`. This function requires two arguments: the path of the new directory and the permissions for it.

`int mkdir (const char *filename, mode_t mode)`

Here's an example:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

if (mkdir("/some/directory", S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO) == -1) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

Keypoints:

1. **Permissions:** The `mode` argument in `mkdir` specifies the directory's permissions. For best practice it is recommended to use an integer-alias for `mode`. `S_IRWXU`, `S_IRWXG` and `S_IRWXO` represent read, write and execute permissions for the user, group and others, respectively. In this example, `S_IROTH | S_IXOTH` is used instead of `S_IRWXO` for others, which allows others to read and execute but not write.
2. **Error Checking:** If `mkdir` returns `-1`, an error occurred. Using `strerror(errno)` will give you a human-readable error message. Common errors include the directory already existing (check for `EEXIST` in `errno`)
3. **Documentation Reference:** For a deeper understanding of permission bits, you can refer to the GNU C Library documentation: [GNU Permission Bits](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Permission-Bits.html)

Comment: Why not use `perror()`?  That avoids the mistake of writing to `stdout` instead of `stderr`, for one thing!

Comment: *For best practice it is recommended to use an integer-alias for mode.* That's completely unnecessary.  The values of those aliases are [fixed by POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html) (bolding mine): "The <sys/stat.h> header shall define the following symbolic constants for the file mode bits encoded in type mode_t, **with the indicated numeric values**."

Comment: I was just reciting the official recommendations from GNU. See for yourself if you open the Sourcelink. Here is the excerpt -> *Warning: Writing explicit numbers for file permissions is bad practice. Not only is it not portable, it also requires everyone who reads your program to remember what the bits mean. **To make your program clean use the symbolic names.***

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified version of Jens Harms code that does not use recursion.

```
FILE * fopen_mkdir(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
    char *p = strdup(path);
    char *sep = strchr(p+1, '/');
    while(sep != NULL)
    {
        *sep = '\0';
        if (mkdir(p, 0755) && errno != EEXIST)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "error while trying to create %s\n", p);
        }
        *sep = '/';
        sep = strchr(sep+1, '/');
    }
    free(p);
    return fopen(path, mode);
}
```

Comment: To be sure, this is nice code.  But user asked for log file creation as part of the desired answer and I do not see that in your code.  To be fair, I think everybody else overlooked this part too, so I'm definitely not going to ding your response.  Thanks...

Comment: The file is created by calling the function `FILE *f = fopen_mkdir("/path/to/log.txt", "w");`

Comment: Why do you think that `0777` is appropriate here?  I see no reason to grant write permission globally regardless of umask, and would use `0755` for this.

Comment: @TobySpeight I used 0777 based on the comments under Jens Harms' answer and read up on umask after reading your comment. Your suggestion seems reasonable, and I edited my answer accordingly. Thanks!