# Create a directory if it doesn't exist

Tags: c++, windows, file, directory, copy

In my app I want to copy a file to the other hard disk so this is my code:

```
 #include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    string Input = "C:\\Emploi NAm.docx";
    string CopiedFile = "Emploi NAm.docx";
    string OutputFolder = "D:\\test";
    CopyFile(Input.c_str(), string(OutputFolder+CopiedFile).c_str(), TRUE);

    return 0;
}
```

so after executing this, it shows me in the `D:`HDD a file `testEmploi NAm.docx`
but I want him to create the test folder if it doesn't exist.

I want to do that without using the Boost library.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Use the WINAPI [`CreateDirectory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to create a folder.

You can use this function without checking if the directory already exists as it will fail but `GetLastError()` will return `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`:

```
if (CreateDirectory(OutputFolder.c_str(), NULL) ||
    ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS == GetLastError())
{
    // CopyFile(...)
}
else
{
     // Failed to create directory.
}
```

The code for constructing the target file is incorrect:

```
string(OutputFolder+CopiedFile).c_str()
```

this would produce `"D:\testEmploi Nam.docx"`: there is a missing path separator between the directory and the filename. Example fix:

```
string(OutputFolder+"\\"+CopiedFile).c_str()
```

Comment: thanks for fast answer
so how can i mix it with the CopyFile member

Comment: Prior to calling `CopyFile()` call `CreateDirectory()` to create `OutputFolder`.

Comment: Does this function gets "ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS" if path is just "C:\" ? Thanks

Comment: [For those who reach the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001284/incompatible-with-parametr-of-type-lpcwstr) `argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"`.

Comment: Small caveat: CreateDirectory also returns if lpPathName points to an existing *file* so one might wrongly assume it is a directory, and in this case the CopyFile call would probably fail

Comment: There is an issue with this solution I think, because you need to include the windows.h library which has a lot of macros that ignore scope. This can make it completely incompatible with other libraries.

Comment: @baru if you get LPCWSTR you can change the function **CreateDirectory** to **CreateDirectoryA**

Answer (score 71):

```
#include <experimental/filesystem> // or #include <filesystem> for C++17 and up
    
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;


if (!fs::is_directory("src") || !fs::exists("src")) { // Check if src folder exists
    fs::create_directory("src"); // create src folder
}
```

Comment: Just need to compile with -lstdc++fs

Comment: The logic is flawed if "src" points to a file instead of a directory, you should add a call to is_directory (or whatever it is called)

Comment: @stijn Fixed it! ;)

Comment: It is in C++17 now

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect modern C++17 and up

Comment: You don't need the `if` at all. Just do `fs::create_directory`, and if the directory already exists, it won't do anything.

Comment: Is this platform agnostic?

Comment: @tzg Yes. C++17 and up provide a [Filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem).

Comment: As HolyBlackCat mentioned, we don't need `if`. Moreover, `std::filesystem::create_directory` returns `true` if it creates the directory(not exist one), else returns `false`. Also, use `create_directories` to create nested directories like `path/to/nested/dir`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat This is not true, `fs::create_directory` ***may or may not throw***, depending on how the underlying OS reports API errors.  You either need `if`, must catch the error, must provide a reference to an error code variable, or accept that your project is limited to a single OS. See `29.11.6 Error reporting` in the C++ standard for details.

Comment: @cz I'm talking specifically about `if (!fs::is_directory("src") || !fs::exists("src"))`. Sure, you can do something like `error_code ec{}; fs::create_directory("path", ec;) if (ec) ...`.

Answer (score 42):

Probably the easiest and most efficient way is to use boost and the boost::filesystem functions. This way you can build a directory simply and ensure that it is platform independent.

```
const char* path = _filePath.c_str();
boost::filesystem::path dir(path);
if(boost::filesystem::create_directory(dir))
{
    std::cerr<< "Directory Created: "<<_filePath<<std::endl;
}
```

[boost::filesystem::create_directory - documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#create_directory)

Comment: Which headers do you need to use here?

Comment: For Googlers like myself, `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>` Also, pass `-lboost_filesystem -lboost_system` to the linker

Answer (score 21):

Here is the simple way to create a folder.......

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void CreateFolder(const char * path)
{   
    if(!CreateDirectory(path ,NULL))
    {
        return;
    }
}


CreateFolder("C:\\folder_name\\")
```

This above code works well for me.

Comment: Thanks for including the .h file reference, which for us newbies is hard to determine.

Comment: There is an issue with this solution I think, because the windows.h library has a lot of macros that ignore scope. This can make it completely incompatible with other libraries.

Answer (score 10):

`_mkdir` will also do the job.

```
_mkdir("D:\\test");
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fkk4dzw.aspx

Comment: With ref. to the asked question, use `_mkdir(OutputFolder.c_str())`.

Answer (score 9):

Since c++17, you can easily do this cross-platform with:

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
int main() {
bool created_new_directory = false;
bool there_was_an_exception = false;

try {
  created_new_directory
      = std::filesystem::create_directory("directory_name");
} catch(std::exception & e){
there_was_an_exception = true;
// creation failed
}
if ((not created_new_directory) and (not there_was_an_exception)) {
    // no failure, but the directory was already present.
  }
}
```

Note, that this version is very useful, if you need to know, whether the directory is actually newly created.
And I find the documentation on cppreference slightly difficult to understand on this point: If the directory is already present, this function returns false.

This means, you can more or less atomically create a new directory with this method.

Comment: Is the directory creation guaranteed to be atomic? Just asking because I couldn't find such information on cppreference.com.

Comment: No, therefore the "more or less". It depends on the operating system and cannot be guaranteed by c++. I think it is atomic in POSIX systems if using local filesystems (not over network), but don't quote me on that. Although I have used this on Linux and not gotten a failure of atomicity, yet.

Answer (score 6):

**OpenCV Specific**

Opencv supports filesystem, probably through its dependency Boost.

```
#include <opencv2/core/utils/filesystem.hpp>
cv::utils::fs::createDirectory(outputDir);
```

Comment: P.S. - This answer helps mostly students/researchers who have to work on computer vision projects but do not need Boost specifically.

Comment: Does this function destroy the folder if it exists?

Comment: @KansaiRobot https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/17234f82d025e3bbfbf611089637e5aa2038e7b8/modules/core/src/utils/filesystem.cpp#L232 It just emulates linux mkdir command. So if a folder already exists, it returns true. No directory should get deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`CreateDirectory (char *DirName, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES Attribs);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363855.aspx)

If the function succeeds it returns non-zero otherwise `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

This works in GCC:

Taken from:
[Creating a new directory in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430248/creating-a-new-directory-in-c)

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct stat st = {0};

if (stat("/some/directory", &st) == -1) {
    mkdir("/some/directory", 0700);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **cstdlib**

Although- http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/j3wTURfi/

```
#include <cstdlib>

const int dir= system("mkdir -p foo");
if (dir< 0)
{
     return;
}
```

you can also check if the directory exists already by using

```
#include <dirent.h>
```

Comment: this isn't portable, as `-p` option doesn't work with windows mkdir version.