# CreateDirectory creates folder under current directory?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, directory

I am using vs 2010 in windows.
In my program, I want to create a new directory under the current directory.
I use

```
TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];  

GetModuleFileName( NULL, szPath, MAX_PATH );
```

And the string of szPath is "E:\A20J\Bin\***.exe".
But when I use:

```
BOOL bol = CreateDirectory("Path", NULL);
```

bol becomes `1`, which means successful.
But under the "E:\A20J\Bin\", I found no such directory as "Path" even after refreshing, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path of the executable is not indicative of the directory in which the current process is executing. Use [`GetCurrentDirectory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934(v=vs.85).aspx) to detemine the directory in which the process is executing, and the directory `"Path"` will have been created there. If you wish to create the directory in the same directory as the binary then some string manipulation is required to construct the path.

---

Note that [`CreateDirectory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855(v=vs.85).aspx) returns non-zero *only* if it creates the directory. The directory may already exist which you may wish to not treat as a failure (see this old answer of mine [Create a directory if it doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235679/create-a-directory-if-it-doesnt-exist/9235708#9235708)).