# Create directory in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, file-io, directory, filesystems

I'm making a simple game in DirectX and C++.
But I want to create a directory in Documents for the settings etc.

But I don't know how I need to do this?

Can someone help me?

Comment: Is this `c++` or `visual-c++`? What have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a Directory if it doesn't exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235679/create-a-directory-if-it-doesnt-exist)

Comment: Did you try OpenGL or more recently Vulkan instead of DirectX? You live in a dying world...

Answer (score 23):

The C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) does not know about [directories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)). C++17 has [`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) standard header.

If your implementation is C++17 compliant (it probably is not), use [`std::filesystem::create_directory`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory)

Otherwise, use [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) primitives. Be aware that the notion of directory can be OS specific (i.e. different in one OS from another, perhaps even between different [file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system)). For Windows, study the [WinAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/apiindex/windows-api-list) (so consider [CreateDirectoryA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/FileAPI/nf-fileapi-createdirectorya)). For Linux, look into its [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) (so consider [mkdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html))

Some frameworks, notably [Qt](https://qt.io/), [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/), [Boost](https://boost.org/), provide common wrappers above them.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a simple mkdir from `<direct.h>` to create directory

```
_mkdir("C:\\Data\\FolderName");
```

Comment: This is a Windows-only solution. (which is good related to this question)

Comment: What it returns? It says `Return value ignored: _mkdir()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Visual Studio's [`<filesystem>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874694.aspx)

There is a function [`create_directory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874750.aspx) that has the signature

```
template<class Path>
inline bool create_directory(
   const Path& Pval
);
```

You can find the user's Documents directory using [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx) which has the signature

```
HRESULT SHGetKnownFolderPath(
  _In_     REFKNOWNFOLDERID rfid,
  _In_     DWORD            dwFlags,
  _In_opt_ HANDLE           hToken,
  _Out_    PWSTR            *ppszPath
);
```

In this case the `REFKNOWNFOLDERID` you want to use is [`FOLDERID_Documents`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx)

Note this is specific to Visual Studio. The [C++ `<filesystem>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) library is still in the works (i.e. experimental) for now, but hopefully is coming soon!

Comment: As a note, for settings you should use ``FOLDERID_LocalAppData`` as your root folder rather than ``FOLDERID_Documents``. Documents would be an appropriate place for screenshots and 'save games', but settings are not files users need to see polluting up their Documents.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have C++17 yet and look for a platform agnostic solution, use
[ghc::filesystem](https://github.com/gulrak/filesystem).
The header-ony code is compatible to C++17 (in fact a backport) and easy to migrate later on.

Answer (score -4):

For visual studio:

```
System::IO::Directory::CreateDirectory(yourDir);
```

Comment: The question is about C++, not .NET