# How to set directory properties?

Tags: c++, file, winapi, mfc

I can use WinApi `CreateDirectory` to create a directory. How do I set the directory's properties like creation time, last access time and last write time?

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235679/create-a-directory-if-it-doesnt-exist) topic can help you.

Comment: 10 seconds of googling showed me you need the [SetFileTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933(v=vs.85).aspx) function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SetFileTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933.aspx) API call can be used with files as well as directories. The first parameter is documented as:

> hFile: A handle to the file **or directory**.

Comment: Thanks! I think SetFileTime can work.                                                      But I have another question: how to get a directory's handle?            Maybe CreateFile can be used to get the directory's handle?

Comment: @zet: Yes, `CreateFile` can be used to get a handle to a directory, as [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933.aspx).