# How do I create a directory without using wide strings in C++?

Tags: c++, create-directory

I'm trying to create a directory so that I can put a file into it.

My code:

```
string Set;
...
CreateDirectory("Game/Sets/" + Set, NULL); // I'm trying to have something like this. CreateDirectory needs wide strings, but Set is narrow.
```

The variable `Set` is a narrow string.

I think I might need something other than `CreateDirectory`, but I don't know what.

Comment: Could you explain what is "wide string"?

Comment: You can look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430248/creating-a-new-directory-in-c

Comment: @Olia_Pavliuk I'm assuming they mean wide strings as in ones with 2-4 byte characters (`wchar_t`). This example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235679/create-a-directory-if-it-doesnt-exist uses the `WINAPI` to create a directory using `c strings`

Comment: @Olia_Pavliuk The strings with `L` before them.

Comment: Should this be tagged for `winapi`?

Comment: @Olia_Pavliuk I use windows. Thanks though.

Comment: @drescherjm I don't think so. I don't _need_ `winapi`, but I can use it.

Comment: @Fizz Thank you. That's what I meant.

Comment: You didn't specify what is wrong with the code as written. Does it fail to compile? Does it fail to create the directory? If so, did you check the result of `CreateDirectory` - does it indicate an error? Do the directories `Game` and `Game/Sets` exist when you execute the code?

Comment: Those directories are created initially. I'm trying to create the rest of the directories if they don't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `string::c_str()` member function to get the corresponding `const char*` (AKA `LPCSTR`):

```
string Set;
...
CreateDirectory(("Game/Sets/" + Set).c_str(), NULL);
```

But it is probably better to use a temporary variable:

```
string Set;
...
string fullDir = "Game/Sets/" + Set;
CreateDirectory(fullDir.c_str(), NULL);
```

It can happen that you are compiling a UNICODE program. If that is the case, you will get an error because `const char*` is not convertible to `const wchar_t*`. The solution is to call the ANSI version of the function:

```
CreateDirectoryA(fullDir.c_str(), NULL);
```

If you prefer you can use the ANSI function even if there is no error, just to be extra consistent.

Remember that `CreateDirectory` is actually a macro that expands to     `CreateDirectoryW` or `CreateDirectoryA` depending on the project configuration. You can use any one of these three names as you see fit.

Comment: Thank you **SO** much! I was trying to get this straight for a long time! :D