# How can I check for the existence of a directory in a c program and create it if it isn't there

Tags: c, linux, directory, segmentation-fault

similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430248/creating-a-new-directory-in-c) here.

But it only covers for a single directory level. For example if you gave `/home/mypc/directory` and if only `directory` doesn’t exist, it creates one. but when it comes to `/home/mypc/directory/directory2` where both `directory`  and `directory2` doesn't exist, It gives a segmentation fault error. Could anyone suggest a suitable method for this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are going to use `mkdir` to create the directory just add `-p`.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stat st = {0};

if (stat("/home/mypc/directory/directory2", &st) == -1) {
    system("mkdir --mode=744 -p /home/mypc/directory/directory2");
}
```

Comment: then what does it it do.  could you explain

Comment: First it will verify the status of the directory. If it cannot obtain this status the directory does not exists. So you call the system to execute `mkdir` who creates the full path with `-p`.

Comment: @Lucas, there are reasons other than non-existence that `stat` might fail, (eg, permissions, too many symbolic links, a component of the path is not a directory, etc.) so it is incorrect to claim that stat failure implies non-existence.

Comment: -1: Using `system` is not a very good solution: inefficiency of forking a process, dependency on `PATH`, vulnerability to [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection), won't easily work with a file path with spaces...

Comment: @WilliamPursell You are correct, as the documentation describes.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to depend on external processes, you could just write a recursive function to create a directory hierarchy:

```
int mkdirhier(char const* target) {
    int r = 0;

    struct stat st = {0};
    if (-1 != stat(target, &st))
        return 0; // already exists

    char* parent = strdup(target);
    if (strcmp(dirname(parent), target))
        r = mkdirhier(parent); // recurse

    if (parent)
        free(parent);

    if (!r && (r = mkdir(target, 0700)))
        perror(target);

    return r;
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e8f06c1a9d48ef4)</kbd>**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>

int mkdirhier(char const* target);

int main() {
    char buf[1024];
    srand(time(NULL));

    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "./tree/some%d/dir%d/sub", rand(), rand());
    mkdirhier(buf);

    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "/nopermissions/tree/some%d/dir%d/sub", rand(), rand());
    return mkdirhier(buf);
}
```

Prints

```
gcc main.c; ./a.out; find .
/nopermissions: Permission denied
.
./tree
./tree/some1804649601
./tree/some1804649601/dir1553142090
./tree/some1804649601/dir1553142090/sub
./main.cpp
./a.out
./main.c
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the path into its components, and check each and every component of the path. So for the path `/home/mypc/directory/directory2` you check and possibly create, in order

1. `/home`
2. `/home/mypc`
3. `/home/mypc/directory`
4. `/home/mypc/directory/directory2`

Comment: `#define fileLocation "/home/laksith/Desktop/log/lp"` actually Im going to give this as a macro . so when a person give any directory editing the line the files should be stored there.