# Create folder if it doesn't exist, do nothing if it does

Tags: c++, linux, directory, mkdir

I want to create a folder named `sessionname`. If a folder with this name already exists it is fine, and I don't want to do anything.

Right now I do this:

```
finalpath = "/home/Documents"    
finalpath.append(path + "/" + sessionname);
    if (mkdir(finalpath.c_str(), S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH) == -1)
    {
        //INVALID PATH
        std::cout << "path is invalid, cannot create sessionnamefolder" << std::endl;
        throw std::exception();
    }
```

This code errors, if the folder `/home/Documents/sessionname` exists because the folder couldn't be created.

How can I check if `mkdir` fails because the string was invalid or because the string was vaild but the folder already exists ?

Comment: Read http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkdir.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430248/creating-a-new-directory-in-c

Comment: Have you read [the `mkdir` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html)? Have you checked what errors you can get from it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I check if mkdir fails because the string was invalid or because the string was vaild but the folder already existed?

Return code from `mkdir()` shows if function is successful or not. In case of failure you should check special variable `errno`, details can be found on [man
page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno)

```
if (mkdir(finalpath.c_str(), S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH) == -1)
{
    if( errno == EEXIST ) {
       // alredy exists
    } else {
       // something else
        std::cout << "cannot create sessionnamefolder error:" << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        throw std::runtime_error( strerror(errno) );
    }
}
```

Note: this is common method for Linux/Unix (and other POSIX systems) library functions to report details of error condition.

Comment: you need to include <sys/stat.h> for S_IRWXU, S_IRWXG .

Comment: Did you mean `std::runtime_error` instead of `std::runtime_exception`?

Comment: I cannot find any documentation that goes over a directory already existing, but exists with different permissions than your call to mkdir.

Comment: Downvote because OP said not to throw an error only if folder exists with the same name. But this code will not throw an error if a file exists with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, it's mentioned on the `mkdir` - make a directory - manual page, one of the errors `mkdir`  can get you is if `[EEXIST]` -> The named file exists. So it fails. See [**here**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkdir.html) for the `mkdir` main page. And here is a possible [**duplicate**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430248/creating-a-new-directory-in-c) on stackoverflow.

Comment: Probably OP does not know where to get that error code from.