# Adding multiple directories to mkdir

Tags: c, mkdir

I'm trying to write a function that creates a folder inside a folder 
for example:
'outerfolder/innerfolder'
but when I put it inside the mkdir function I get an error, 
how am I suppose to do that?

```
int check;
char* dirname = "outerfolder/innerfolder";


check = mkdir(dirname);

// check if directory is created or not 
if (!check)
    printf("Directory created\n");
else {
    printf("Unable to create directory\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

which doesnt work.

Comment: What error are u getting?

Comment: Check the value of `errno` for more information about what happened, or use `perror()`.  One note is that `outerfolder` needs to already exist, so if you want to create both, you'll need to call `mkdir()` twice.

Comment: I tried making a new folder that does not exist , still won't let me

Comment: See: [How can I create directory tree in C++/Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675039/how-can-i-create-directory-tree-in-c-linux) — Even though the question is tagged C++, the code shown in my answer is explicitly C code that can be compiled with a C++ compiler (without change of meaning).  Also consider the merits and demerits of `system("mkdir -p outerfolder/innerfolder");`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct stat st = {0};

if (stat("/some/directory", &st) == -1) {
    mkdir("/some/directory", 0700);
}
```

from [Creating a new directory in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430248/creating-a-new-directory-in-c)

Comment: doesn't work, unistd won't allow me top open.

Comment: make sure you (your program) have the access rights you need (admin).. also try wit 777 to enable all prophiles to  read write and execute rights for the moment..

Comment: You have to create `/some` first, if it doesn't exist, and only then `/some/directory`.  This code doesn't attempt to do that.

Comment: the point is not to reinvent the wheel..creating a recursive version of the standard `mkdir` function is not good idea.. may be he should create the logic to use `mkdir` for creating nested directories..